# Confused about the correct replacement lcd screen for my laptop

Tags: display, resolution, lcd

I am trying to replace the lcd screen on my Dell Latitude 6430u (the reason for the need to replace it is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1301125/several-vertical-lines-of-defective-pixels))

I'm having a problem finding the correct replacement. On Dell's website I find that the model of screen I use is [this one](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-14-inch-356-cm-hd-lcd-display-for-latitude-6430u-e5440-e6440/apd/jy0dk/monitors-monitor-accessories). But when I search using the part number JY0DK, all the screens I find are for 1600x900 resolution. However my screen resolution is 1366x768 (this is the highest resolution that appears as an option on my display settings, using xubuntu 16.04).

Will there be a problem if I install a screen with 1600x900 resolution?

What worries me is that some vendors even include the warning "1600x900 resolution LCD not compatible with 1366x768" If I knew that all they mean is that a 1600x900 display will work but only at 1366x768 resolution, then I would not be too worried.

Comment: Contact the vendors and ask for clarification